# SoundCloud API Often Returning 502 Error?

Tags: php, api, soundcloud, http-status-codes

We've been uploading tracks to SoundCloud via the API for about a year and a half reliably, haven't had any real issues. Recently we've been getting a lot of **502 Errors** and can't work out if it's a problem our end, or a problem with SoundCloud.

We use the PHP API Client and no one else seems to be reporting issues: https://github.com/mptre/php-soundcloud

We have a full log of dates/times when the **502 Errors** occur. They're often grouped together which makes me think it's an issue with SoundCloud's servers (as we're not getting any issues reported with ours at these times).

**All times are in BST (UTC+1)** - Just wondered if a SoundCloud engineer could see if these tie up with server issues at SoundCloud etc or whether it's something wrong our end. As you can see, they're getting more and more frequent.

```
2014-01-04 14:52:51
2014-01-15 01:22:49
2014-02-06 16:03:11
2014-06-04 13:47:08
2014-06-10 21:25:35
2014-06-13 17:24:25
2014-06-15 11:18:56
2014-06-15 11:29:55
2014-06-17 14:38:07
2014-06-19 19:24:14
2014-06-22 18:08:40
2014-06-23 19:13:17
2014-06-26 12:11:03
2014-06-26 18:33:06
2014-06-30 11:44:38
2014-06-30 18:23:23
2014-07-03 10:58:18
2014-07-03 13:27:47
2014-07-07 17:47:13
2014-07-24 10:38:35
2014-07-24 10:42:15
2014-07-24 10:43:33
2014-07-24 11:27:51
2014-07-24 12:59:22
2014-07-24 13:08:01
2014-07-24 13:13:37
2014-07-24 13:36:36
2014-07-24 13:36:49
2014-07-24 15:48:21
2014-07-24 15:49:33
2014-07-24 15:51:08
2014-07-24 23:21:11
2014-07-25 08:47:42
2014-07-25 11:22:40
2014-07-25 12:14:31
2014-07-25 14:25:59
2014-07-25 14:37:03
2014-07-25 14:37:45
2014-07-25 14:38:01
2014-07-25 14:38:36
2014-07-25 14:40:30
2014-07-25 14:44:40
2014-07-25 14:45:24
2014-07-25 14:46:31
2014-07-25 14:47:16
2014-07-25 15:02:32
2014-07-25 15:02:41
2014-07-25 15:12:03
2014-07-29 12:49:04
2014-07-29 12:50:54
2014-07-29 12:51:05
2014-07-29 12:51:30
2014-07-29 12:54:02
2014-07-29 12:54:58
2014-07-29 12:56:27
2014-07-29 13:03:36
2014-07-29 13:04:51
2014-07-29 13:27:48
2014-07-29 14:33:30
2014-07-29 14:44:07
2014-07-29 14:44:37
2014-07-29 15:13:11
2014-07-29 15:17:44
2014-07-29 15:19:31
2014-07-29 15:47:21
2014-07-29 15:49:39
2014-07-29 16:26:10
2014-07-29 16:28:12
2014-07-29 16:33:07
2014-07-29 16:37:50
2014-07-29 16:38:06
2014-07-29 16:45:11
2014-07-29 16:55:42
2014-07-29 16:56:39
2014-07-29 17:04:18
2014-07-29 17:36:52
```

Comment: I'm maitaining my own open source library and not getting that. Would you give it a try?  https://github.com/njasm/soundcloud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be just an issue with SoundCloud's servers. They eventually posted it on their service status page and after that our issues went away.